# Finding the formula of a function based on output

Tags: functions

This is probably something super simple, but I can't find it in my book, and I don't even know what to search for because I don't know what to call it.

I'm not looking for this specific answer, but how would I approach a problem like this.

$$ \mbox{If}\ f(x - 4) = 3x + 2,\ \mbox{find}\ f(-2).$$

So, $3x+2$ is the output, being modified by the formula I need to find. I don't know how to algebraically find that equation without brute forcing. For what it's worth, the answer above was apparently $-12$.

Edit. Answer was not -12, but still had trouble figuring out how to approach to find correct answer.

Comment: What would you set $x$ to so that $x-4 = -2$?

Comment: 2 would be the x value there, but I'm trying to find what f(x), knowing that if I pass in x-4, it'll spit out 3x+4

Comment: I've tried asking some friends, and they seem to approach it as f(x)=3x+4, and start working with 3x+4 to find it, in a way such as 3(-2 - 4) + 4, but that outputs -14, not the expected -12

Comment: If $f(x-4) = 3x+4$, then $f(2-4) = f(-2) = 3(2)+4$.

Comment: Either your question or your friends are wrong.

Comment: If you prefer, let $y=x-4$, then $x=y+4$ and $f(y) = 3(y+4)+4 = 3y + 16$. Then $f(-2) = 3(-2)+16 = 10$.

Comment: So, essentially, are you treating f(x-4)=3x+4 as a whole new formula, and substituting -2 in for x?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20507/discussion-between-robert-and-copper-hat). (it popped up a link saying this...?)

Comment: I don't know what your last comment means. The function $f$ is defined by the pairs of numbers $(x-4,3x+\text{whatever})$. So, you want to find the right value when the left value is $-2$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm off too sleep now.

Comment: What would I call this sort of operation so I can research it further, I don't even know what to look up.

Comment: I'm around for a while if you want to chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps in full detail
$$ f(x-4)=3x+2 $$
$$ \frac13 f(x-4)=x+\frac23 $$
$$ \frac13 f(x-4)=x+\frac23 +\frac13-\frac13 $$
$$ \frac13 f(x-4)=x+1-\frac13 $$
$$ \frac13 f(x-4)=x+1-5+5-\frac13 $$
$$ \frac13 f(x-4)=x-4+5-\frac13 $$
$$ f(x-4)=3(x-4)+15-1 $$
$$ f(x-4)=3(x-4)+14 $$
$$ f(s)=3s+14 $$
So now we have
$$ f(-2)=3(-2)+14 =-6+14=8$$
We can also skip all of this and just use the fact that
$$ x-4 =-2 $$
$$ x =-2 +4 =2 $$
So now we have
$$ f(2-4)=f(-2)=3(2)+2 $$
$$=6+2=8 $$
Either way,
$$f(-2)\not =-12$$

Comment: I think it should be $f(s) = 3s+16$.

Comment: @copper.hat, hmm where do you suppose the error is in my answer?

Comment: I just realised that there are two different formulas for $f$ in the question. They differ by 2.

Comment: So I stayed up most of the night messing with this formula, and the way that seemed closest was x-4=-2, then x=2, and you can use that to solve in the 3x+2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want $f(-2)$ and you know that $f(x-4)=3x+2$, then you want $x-4=-2$. Does that help?

By the way, I think your supposed answer of $-12$ is incorrect.

Comment: The formula has changed.

Comment: Got it. My phone app doesn't update quickly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to look at your question.

1) you just want to compute $f(-2)$. For this, you need to find $x$ such that $x-4=-2$. Obviously, $x=2$ and $f(-2)=3\cdot2+2$.

$$f(-2)=8.$$

2) you want to get the expression for $f(x)$ instead of $f(x-4)$. In this case, use a change of variable $y=x-4$, hence $x=y+4$, and $f(y)=3x+2=3y+14$.

$$f(x)=3x+14.$$